# Execute Hackificator From PHP

Tags: ocaml, hhvm, hacklang

When I try to execute Facebook HHVM hackficator from PHP I get this error

`Fatal error: exception Failure("unstable www state before modification")`

I googled error and found reference inside the code written in OCaml

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/hack/tools/hackificator/hackificator.ml

but I have no idea does that mean?, but I do see a reference to www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `hh_client` executable was called and returned something other than `"No errors!"`.

Comment: Yep, exactly. You need to run `hh_client` and fix any errors that the typechecker points out. You should be running `hh_client` often anyways, since that is what enforces most of Hack's type system. http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/install.hack.bootstrapping.php has details on this process.